# Strength of atomic update in Firestore increment

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Firestore user recently diving into a concept of "atomic" update, especially Firestore documents' increment update. There is a [classic article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html) on Firestore increment in context of atomic update. And here comes my question.

Q, How strong is this atomic `increment(number)` update? Does this operation really have no limitation when it comes to operating truly atomically?

Let me explain a bit of details with an example case. We know that Firestore has a write limitation of 10,000 (up to 10 MiB per second) per db instance, and we also know that Firestore's `increment` method updates documents atomically. So, I hope to know if the below extreme example case would work perfectly atomically.

> This Firestore instance only has a single document, and numerous users-maybe 10000 users maximum- update a single document using increment method, which increments a same field value as much as a random double number between 0 and 1 each, WITHIN a single second: 10000 updates in 1 second;

Above case makes use of Firestore write rate limit per second as much as possible, and all operations are updating a single field of same document. If `increment` method deals with update requests truly atomically, we might say all 10000 details will be calculated correctly into a single field.

But, this is only theoretic and conceptual idea, and it seems really hard for Firestore(or even any other db systems) to make no exception when it performs such an extreme set of `increment` operations when it has to deal with other upcoming operations linearly. It means that the Firestore instance would keep going on with upcoming API requests. This is a real world problem, actually. Let's say a lovely singer, Ariana Grande's Instagram post is just uploaded. If we deal with the event with Firestore document, we would have to deal with thousands of `increment requests` for likes per a single second.

So, i hope to know if there is truly no limitations for `atomic increment` method even there comes a set of high number of extremely concurrent `increment requests` to very few number of target documents. Hope this question reach to firebase gurus in the community! Comments are really welcomed! Thanks in advance [:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but I'll try to help anyway by explaining how Firestore and its `increment` operation work.

Firestore's main write limits come from the fact that data needs to be synchronized between data centers for each write operation. This is not a quota-type limit, but a physical limit of how fast data can be pushed across the wires.

Since you talk about frequent writes to a single document, you're going to sooner hit the soft limit of 1 sustained write per second per document. This is also caused by the physical nature of how the database works, and needs to synchronize the documents and indexes between servers/data centers.

While using the `increment()` operation means that no roundtrip is needed between the client and the server, it makes no difference to the data that needs to be read/written on the servers themselves. Therefore it makes no difference to the [documented throughput limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits).

If you need to perform counts beyond the documented throughput limits, have a look at the documentation on using a [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters).

Comment: So the `increment()` will work all fine if we meet all the limitations, and the limitations are quite various tho. This is cool enough for me ATM. Thank you for the answer! I've missed the other kinds of limitations more than few ones in the example. Learning from master [:

Comment: What I didn’t understand, is what would happen if 5 people hit "like" at the exact same second. Only 1 `increment` would take place, some of them, or all of them?

Comment: These are atomic increments, which the server handles. If you send 5 increment operations (from one client or multiple), the value will be incremented 5 times.